# What's the word for those video rectangles of each person on Skype?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

In a group call on a Skype or Zoom session, there are these video screens for each person:

[image: skype]

What are these video containers called?

Comment: I don't think there's a specific name for those rectangles. You could call them 'video pop-ups'.

Comment: *Windows? Viewports? Panes?*

Comment: Instructions on the Zoom app and on the Owl Labs site refer to shared screens. https://www.owllabs.com/offers/zoom-room-setup-guide.

Comment: @Snow Are these moving images? My experience of Skype may be limited by our antiquated server environment, but these are always static for me. They move in Zoom.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think they are moving images in the new Skype versions.

Comment: Are you asking specifically what they are called when they contain imagery of each participant in the call or just in general what do you call a small frame containing imagery.  I might call the specific use here a “participant video feed” but I just made that up. And if it’s static then it might just be participant image or picture.

Comment: @Jim I mean the feed, not a static image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been using Zoom for work reasons almost every day since the middle of March. My initial thought was "frame" or "video frame", but I couldn't find a single reference using that term anywhere on the web.

So I continued searching and finally landed on a page entitled "Glossary of Zoom Terms". https://vtcri.kayako.com/article/160-glossary-of-zoom-terms. It is maintained by Virginia Tech's Fralin Biomedical Research Institute (FBRI). The Glossary had no answer to the question, but the site did offer something called the "FBRI Help Center": https://vtcri.kayako.com.

I provided my email to the Help Center and was able to ask what the video rectangles were called. Within a couple of hours, I received an email with an answer.

Here it is: **"Those smaller video screens of your meeting participants are referred to as 'thumbnails.'"**

The message was signed by Bradley Anglin, AV Coordinator, VTC Fralin Biomedical Research Institute. I hope that's helpful.

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten 'thumbnail'. Images and other files in a folder are also called ['thumbnails'](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sevenforums.com%2Fattachments%2Fmusic-pictures-video%2F212897d1486594132t-folder-thumbnails-issues-music-collection-21-05-2012-21-10-24.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sevenforums.com%2Fmusic-pictures-video%2F226421-folder-thumbnails-issues-music-collection.html&tbnid=88Z-S97vj-XdhM&vet=1&docid=bVg3tKgz7a8ecM&w=750&h=437&q=thumbnails%20in%20a%20folder&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim) (+1)

Comment: Not 'thumbnails' when there are two, each filling half a screen, surely?

Comment: In Zoom they are small, even when there are only two. And who says that descriptive terms are always unfailingly accurate? I still call them frames, and most people know what I mean, but the fact remains that "common usage", which is favored by many established users on this site, includes the term "thumbnail".

Comment: And computer image thumbnails surely got their name from artist pencil&paper thumbnails. I think those little Zoom things would be called thumbnails, no matter  what Mr. Anglin said to call them.

Answer (score 3):

The best term I can think of is **video feed**, which is used in [Zoom’s documentation](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360021921032-In-Meeting-Controls?mobile_site=true):

> **Show/Hide self view:** Show or Hide your video feed on the Zoom Room's display. If video is turned off, this will show or hide your name or profile picture.

See [MW’s definition of feed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feed):

> the act or process of feeding a signal (such as an audio or video transmission) to a station for broadcast
>
> also: the signal being fed